# Find the maximum number of edges you can add to a vertex in a directed graph such that the graph has only $3$ paths with given start and end points.

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following directed graph:

[image]

I have to find the maximum number of directed edges that go out of vertex $6$ that I can add such that the graph has only $3$ paths with the vertex $2$ as the starting point and vertex $4$ as the end point.

I have to choose an answer among the next options:

**A.** 1

**B.** 2

**C.** 3

**D.** 4

I realize that no matter what I add out of vertex $6$, I will always have the paths

$$[2, 1, 4]$$

$$[2, 5, 3, 4]$$

That start in $2$ and end in $4$. So I have to find the numbers of directed edges that go out of vertex $6$ that would only add another path that starts in vertex $2$ and ends in vertex $4$. But I don't see how I could do that.

If I add the directed edge $[6, 1]$ we would also have the paths

$$[2, 5, 6, 1, 4]$$

$$[2, 6, 1, 4]$$

so we would have $4$ paths that start in vertex $2$ and end in vertex $4$, while we need $3$ such paths. I think the same things happen if I add other type of edges that go out of vertex $6$. But $0$ is not an option. So what am I doing wrong? I either am looking at this from the wrong angle or I have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that adding an edge to vertex 1, 3 or 4 will result in more than three paths from vertex 2 to vertex 4. However, you can also add an edge to vertex 2 or 5. These options will create less paths, since all vertices in a path must be unique so you cannot reenter vertices.

Comment: But if I add $[6, 2]$ or $[6, 5]$ would I have $3$ paths that would start in $2$ and end in $4$? Would those edges add a path to my path list, such that I would have $3$ paths that start in $2$ and end in $4$, since that is what is asked?

Comment: Well consider adding the directed edge $(6, 5)$, then also $(2, 6, 5, 3, 4)$ is a path from vertex 2 to vertex 4. And observe that the directed edge $(6, 2)$ can never be used in any path from vertex 2 to vertex 4.